# Make static cell perform action in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have looked this up everywhere and am trying to narrow down my searches. How would I make the static cell that says "Leave a Suggestion" perform the action that I currently have in my code. 
[image]

`@IBOutlet weak var Suggestion: UITableViewCell!`

This outlet connects the cell to my view controller file

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0 {
       print("pressed")
}
```

This is the code I am trying to get it to perform just so I can tell if it's working.

**EDIT:**
This is the current code I've implemented

```
import UIKit

class AccountViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableViewCell, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 {
                print("pressed")
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Why do you have an outlet to a table view cell? That's not something you should have.

Comment: Where should i make an outlet from my cells to the view controller instead @rmaddy?

Comment: You shouldn't have any outlet for any cells.

Comment: getting rid of the cells still does not  make print("pressed") appear in my output

Comment: Is `didSelectRowAt` called at all? Did you set the table view's `delegate` property?

Comment: I don't believe I've done any of that correctly, could you take a look at my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from your screenshot I would expect that you want to compare `indexPath.section == 1`, not `indexPath.section == 2`.

```
import UIKit

class AccountViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 {
            print("pressed")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed it to indexPath.section == 1 but the action print("pressed") still does not appear in my output

Comment: @NigelDenny where is that method defined? Is it in the tableViewController?

Comment: I'm not sure where to define it, could you take a look at my edit?

Comment: @NigelDenny now you have it inside of viewDidLoad, just move it outside (in the class, but out of viewDidLoad) and add override before it

Comment: after doing this im getting the error "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

Comment: @NigelDenny check updated answer to see how you need it

Comment: Yep, with that exact code I'm still getting that error, strange

Comment: @NigelDenny my mistake, did not check it properly.. look at it now, the first parameter is `_ tableView: UITableView`, not `_ tableView: UITableViewCell`

Comment: @NigelDenny too late, I already identified the error :D.. check the comment above

Answer (score 1):

Since the sections starts from 0, you always have to start from 0 when counting or comparing sections.Thus, this is what you wanted to do:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 {
            print("pressed")
    }
```

Comment: It's okay, however I've implemented your change and it still does not make the print("pressed") appear in my output

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code for the UI you have above?

Comment: Check if the tableView Delegate points to your AccountViewController class. You can do this in InterfaceBuilder in the Storyboard or in your ViewDidLoad function by this: self.tableView.delegate = self .Also (but not related to your question), I would suggest to move your  self.navigationController... code portion from ViewDidLoad to ViewWillAppear and undo these changes in ViewWillDisappear. ViewDidLoad will only be called if the View is being loaded and not when it is being displayed. But keep in mind, ViewWillDisappear will also be called in case you would open a Modal View on top.